# magento search result not displays

Tags: magento

In my magento project the search result not displays. I have customized my magento. I don't know what's happened? Is there is any settings I admin side, Does any one know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alex mentioned, definitely rebuild the search index, and dump your cache.  There are other factors worth looking into as well:

- Make sure that you didn't disable search on your product attributes.  For each attribute, you can select wether or not it is searchable
- Make sure your products' visibility is set to "Catalog, Search", and not just "Catalog".

Answer (score 1):

Try to Rebuild the Search Index in Cache Management